# looking for a numerical solution to the equation

Tags: python, sympy, numeric

I was solving multiple equations and came down to the simplified version below:

```py
import sympy as sp
Diff = sp.Symbol('Diff')
eq1 = 0.0363984561703043*Diff**(-0.333333333333333)*(0.01 - 1.288e-18*(2.576e-18*Diff - 2.79999921278e-7)**(-0.5)) + 0.0363984561703043*Diff**(-0.333333333333333)*(17857.1428571429*(2.576e-18*Diff - 2.79999921278e-7)**0.5 - 434782608695.652) + 1299.94486322516*Diff**0.666666666666667
ans = sp.solve(eq1 - 1, Diff)
print(ans)
```

I need help to solve for the symbol (Diff)? I have tried `solve()` and `nsolve()` but it didn't give a solution with the message:

> 'ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance.
>   (0.00104637107257089658395 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19) Try another
>   starting point or tweak arguments.'

Comment: What does _but couldn't solve_ mean, exactly? There's practically no information to work with here.

Comment: Trying the equation using `abs` for the arguments of the square roots, gives `12173913.220177453`. But for that value the real argument of the square root is negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, let us try plotting your function (I had to increase the x-axis limits several times until I finally found something resembling a root):

```
eq = sp.Abs(eq1 - 1)
xs = np.linspace(-1e6, 2e7, 100)
ys = [eq.evalf(subs={Diff: x}) for x in xs]
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.hlines(0, -1e6, 2e7)
```

[image: plot(abs)]

OK, so if there would be a root, it must be located somewhere around 1.0-1.5*10^7. Now observe the imaginary part of your equation in that region:

```
eq = sp.im(eq1 - 1)
xs = np.linspace(1e7, 1.5e7, 100)
ys = [eq.evalf(subs={Diff: x}) for x in xs]
plt.plot(xs, ys)
plt.hlines(0, 1e7, 1.5e7)
```

[image: plot(im)]

It does not reach zero, which means your function does not have a root, it seems. It does get quite close to zero, though, at that point where we saw the absolute value chart nearly touch it. You can find this point by solving just for the real part:

```
sp.nsolve(sp.re(eq1 - 1), Diff, 1e7)
> 12173913.2204420

eq1.subs(Diff, 12173913.2204420).evalf()
0.999999925494194 + 0.00149499418051858*I
```

Comment: thank you so much KT. This was very helpful to diagnose the issue with the equation.